# Maven package as war : does not consider a folder under src/main/java with *.vm files (velocity templates)

Tags: maven, maven-2

I use Maven to package as war a Java EE project.

I use tomcat-maven-plugin, I do simply "mvn clean tomcat deploy" .

Everything works fine, except a folder which is not packaged into the War file.

This folder is a source folder under src/main/java  with only *.vm files (not .java files) which are my Velocity templates.

Is there a way to tell maven to package this folder ! ( I suspect only package with .java files are considered)

In console I get :

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ accueil_individu ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [accueil_individu] in             [D:\DevSpring\workspace\accueil_individu\target\accueil_individu]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources        [D:\DevSpring\workspace\accueil_individu\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.springframework.security:spring-security-samples-cas-client]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1699 msecs]
[INFO] Building war:   D:\DevSpring\workspace\accueil_individu\target\accueil_individu.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as    'true')
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ accueil_individu <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ accueil_individu ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://pcwebapps02.ifma.fr:8080/accueil_individu  
[INFO] OK - Application déployée pour le chemin de contexte /accueil_individu
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource files like the velocity template files that should end up in the classpath of the runtime should be in src/main/resources and not in /src/main/java

Read more about the Maven standard directory layout here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Thank you so much ! I just move my folder from src/main/java to src/main/resources, works like a charm !